# Solving a non-linear constrained linear function optimization

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

Given $k \in \mathbb{N}$, the $k$-vector-norm is defined as the sum of the $k$ largest entries of a vector (largest w.r.t. to absolute value). So if $k=1$, then the $k$-norm is actually the supremum norm, if $k=n$ (where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$), then $||x||_k = ||x||_1$ is the $L_1$ norm.

**I have the following optimization problem**: Given $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $k$, find $v$ with $||v||_k \leq 1$ minimizing $v^Tx$.

Is there any chance I can solve this analytically? I have a good idea of how the optimal solution should look like, but so far I was not able to design a proper algorithm for computing it.

My approaches so far:

1. Using the dual norm I was able to show that the optimal vlaue is actually equal to $b = -max(\frac{1}{k} ||x||_1, ||x||_{\infty})$, but not sure how to use this. If I did not do something wrong here, this would reduce the problem to finding $v$ s.t. $||v||_k <= 1: v^Tx=b$.
2. I tried a Lagrangian formulation approach, but not sure how to proceed here.

Any ideas? Would greatly appreciate some help! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written that the optimal value is $b = -\max\{\|x\|_1/k, \|x\|_\infty\}$ (I did not checked it).

For $v = -\operatorname{sign}(x)/k$ you get
$$x^\top v = -\|x\|_1/k.$$
If $\|x\|_\infty = |x_i|$, you can choose $v = -\operatorname{sign}(x_i) \, e_i$ and get
$$x^\top v = -\|x\|_\infty.$$